# Add all the columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

My question is simple but I am stuck

I have a large csv datset such as shown below

```
Fruit   Apples Oranges Peaches
A          1     2       2
B          1     2       1
C          1     1       1
```

All I need is one column with total number like

```
Fruit  
  A      5         4    3
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for.  You said you want 1 column out but you have one row with many columns.  Can you please fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like `aggregate`, which will sum the values of `Apples`, `Oranges`, and `Peaches` by the category `Fruit`

```
    set.seed(100)
    mydata = data.frame(Fruit = rep(c("A", "B", "C"),  5), 
                Apples = rpois(15, 3), 
                Oranges = rpois(15, 3), 
                Peaches = rpois(15, 3))
    aggregate(cbind(Apples, Oranges, Peaches) ~ Fruit, mydata, sum)
```

which will output one row for each category of `Fruit` along with the totals:

```
     Fruit Apples Oranges Peaches
    1     A     10      17      15
    2     B     12      13      20
    3     C     18      15      23
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df1$Sum <- rowSums(df1[-1])
df1$Sum
#[1] 5 4 3
```

Or use `+` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, df1[-1])
#[1] 5 4 3
```